# How to handle/display errors without a ModelAttribute in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, controller

In my insert/edit form I have a *submit* button to save changes to my model attribute, while I handle delete command by a simple link.

Now I'd like to show delete errors the same way I show global errors for form submission, but it seems I cannot use `BindingResult` without a `ModelAttribute` in my controller method.

For clarity, my code is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete")
public String deleteJob(Integer jobId, BindingResult result) {

    // DELETE BY ID

    return "myView";
}
```

But as expected I get this exception:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be immediately after the model attribute argument in the controller method signature`

Is there any way to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the `BindingResult result`, what you can do is to create your errors and add them in the `Errors` object. and return it to your view

Comment: do you mean `org.springframework.validation.Errors` or a custom `Errors` object?

Comment: Errors object, but it is an interface, you'll have to implement it

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is add an attribute to your domain object - like "delete", bind it to a hidden field on the form and set that to true when the user clicks on the remove button and then submit it to the server to be processed as a model attribute. All validation checks and binding result will behave as expected.